# A program to verify checksums (sfv, md5) after double clicking

Tags: windows

I'm looking for a program that will do a simple thing. I want it to run when I double click a checksum file (most important ones include `sfv`, `md5` etc.) and provide information if a file or files are OK. I don't need to create checksums, I need only to verfiy them.

In addition, the program must:

1. preferably be free althought paid are also fine;
2. run on Windows 10 (so software that are e.g. 5 years old won't qualify)
3. have GUI.
4. be lightweight

I know some programs that can achieve similiar things but they don't meet all my criteria. [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy) would be perfect as it does almost all I need but it is software desgined for fast copying files and it completely replaces the Explorer copy and move functions. [TotalCommander](http://www.ghisler.com/) is not an option as well since I must run it and choose a file to verify its checksum. [HashCheck Shell Extension](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) seems to do what I want but is very old (released in 2009).

Comment: What's the problem with HashCheck extension being old? It does run on Windows 10 and does all you want.

Comment: I was not designed for Windows 10.

Comment: It certainly wasn't designed with Windows 10 in mind (it didn't existed back then), but the program still works there pretty much in the same way as on any other earlier version of Windows. It certainly complies with your requirements. What's the exact problem with that? Or what do you exactly mean by "designed for Windows 10"?

Answer (score 2):

[HashCheck](http://code.kliu.org/hashcheck/) is golden standard here and it works on Windows 10 as good as 8 years ago. If you want sha-3 support you can grab successful HashCheck [fork](https://github.com/gurnec/HashCheck).

There is also similar product [HashTab](http://implbits.com/products/hashtab/) from Implbits, but I always liked HashCheck more.

If speed is a factor (e.g. hashing 50 GB file) I go with [7z](http://www.7-zip.org), which is considerably faster than previously mentioned tools.

Answer (score 0):

Set up associations for files containing checksums (*.sha1/256/512) so that they can be opened in [Veretino](https://github.com/artemvlas/veretino). (Or drag the file into the application window). After this, just double click to perform the check.

It is also easy to store the calculated checksum. Open the file in the app and click the Button (or by context menu -> right click -> calculate (store) the checksum). And that's it...

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/67765)